# Update Json content with javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

Hello guys I got some Problems wiht my Json File

The Filename is `name.json`

```
{   
    "name": "Gerald"
}
```

How can I Change the name to `"Gandalf"` with a function in Javascript

```
function changeNameJson(name){
  let filename= "./name.json";
  let file = fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8');
  let nameAtTheTime = JSON.parse(file);
  let newName=name;
}
```

I tried to find a Solution but i couldn't.

Comment: Your function is incomplete, it doesn't make any changes to the json. You need something like `nameAtTheTime.name = name` to assign the property. You then need to return the `nameAttheTime` object to the function caller to do something else, or write it back to a file.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the function like this:

```
function changeNameJson(name){
    let filename= "./name.json";
    let file = fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8');
    let nameAtTheTime = JSON.parse(file);
    nameAtTheTime.name = name;
}
```

And if you want to save the change into `name.json` file, add this to the end of `changeNameJson` function body :

```
fs.writeFileSync("./name.json",JSON.stringify(nameAtTheTime));
```

Or if you want to make `name.json` file content prettier:

```
fs.writeFileSync("./name.json",JSON.stringify(nameAtTheTime,null,2));
```